# How to use coreData on a background thread with SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am using CoreData with SwiftUI.  I'm having some performance issues and I guess it's loading lot's of objects on the viewContext in the main thread.  I was wondering what is the best way around this?
Prior to SwiftUI I was using:

```
lazy var privateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        
    return managedObjectContext
    
}()
```

And I would use it in:

```
self.privateContext.perform({ ...
```

This worked quite well and I wanted to implement a similar approach in SwiftUI.  I'm using the default coreData template with a PersistenceController Struct.

I can get the viewContext and inject using:

```
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
```

I thought to do something like:

```
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.newBackgroundContext())
```

But not sure what is the best practice?  I am using a fetchRequest in the init for my View:

```
@FetchRequest var items: FetchedResults<Item>

init() {
    
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt_", ascending: true)]
    _items = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)

}
```

Comment: Asking about best practice seems more inline with [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Stackoverflow is more [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions about problems and algorithms.

Comment: Had the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245459/swiftui-coredata-async-fetch.. still haven't found any good solution. I tried async fetch request, but wasn't any improvement.

Comment: I can create and save to a privateContext but the FetchRequest does not update.  I need something like container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true which works for NSFetchedResultsController but for FetchRequest